# How to use ng-options with ng-model to bind with parent scope variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using AngularJS along with UI-router. I've a parent state & a child. A parent state contains a variable which is initialized to `null`. In child state, I've displayed a dropdown as follows

```
<select name="" ng-model='$parent.fruit' ng-options="fruit as fruit.name for fruit in fruit_list">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select a fruit</option>
</select>
```

The `$parent.fruit` returns `null`.

Comment: Share parent state code , are you in nested loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research, I found out, this creates child scope. So need to use `$parent.$parent.fruit` instead of `$parent.fruit`

```
<select name="" ng-model='$parent.$parent.fruit' ng-options="fruit as fruit.name for fruit in fruit_list">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select a fruit</option>
</select>
```

Reference - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/18

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you name your parent controller. You can do so when defining your controller like

```
<div ng-controller="parentController as pc">
```

And then in your code here, you could use the example

```
<select ng-model="selectedFruit" ng-options="fruit.name for fruit in pc.fruit"></select>
```

You had a mistake trying to put ng-options on the option tag if you want to use the option tag, you can use an ng-repeat.

```
<select name="" ng-model="selectedFruit">
  <option ng-repeat="fruit in pc.fruits" value="{{fruit.name}}">{{fruit.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Here is a good place to find an example, if these don't satisfy your needs: https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/08/11/a-brief-walk-through-of-the-ng-options-in-angularjs/